# How to save PgAdmin 4 setup

Tags: pgadmin-4

On every upgrade of PgAdmin 4 (currently at version 1.5), we lost all our server definitions as well as other config details. Quite annoying when one has to deal with a dozen servers :)

I have not been able to find where the server definitions are stored so to try making a copy before installing the new version.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Server definitions and other configurations of pgAdmin4 are stored at,

Linux/Mac:

```
~/.pgadmin/pgadmin4.db
```

Windows:

```
C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin\pgadmin4.db
```

Make a copy of this file somewhere and paste it again at the same location after installation is complete and you are good to go.